# VBA Excel Form. Sum values from two texboxes into a third one and the currency Format coma is wrongly read

Tags: excel, vba, forms

I have a vba form that consist of several textboxes that contain numeric values that represent money. The format of TextBox 1 and TextBox2 is set to be

```
    If IsNumeric(TextBox1.Value) Then TextBox1.Value = Format(TextBox1.Value, "#,##0")

    If IsNumeric(TextBox2.Value) Then [enter image description here][1]TextBox2.Value = Format(TextBox2.Value, "#,##0")
```

So any number that is typed into the texbox will appear with a coma (,) as thousands separator, For example 1000(one thousand) will appear as 1,000; 50000 (fifty thousand) will be shown as 50,000 and so on.

Finally, when I try to sum the two textboxes into the third one with the code below, the coma (,) is being read as a decimal separator, so if for example Textbox1.value = 5,000 and Textbox2.value = 20,000. the sum of those two will appear as 25, and not 25,000 (twenty five thousand)

```
    If IsNumeric(TextBox1.Value) Or IsNumeric(TextBox2.Value) Then


TextBox3.Value = Val(TextBox1.Value) + Val(TextBox2.Value)
```

If i remove the "##,#0" currency formating, it works perfectly, but i need values to be shown with thousand separator, either dot or coma. (using "##.#0") does not work.

Comment: Remove the comma before doing calculations, like `Val(Replace(TextBox1.Value, ",", "")) + Val(Replace(TextBox2.Value, ",", ""))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bear in mind that TextBoxes contain text, meaning string values. Text strings aren't numbers and TextBoxes aren't Excel cells. Before doing calculations with strings the numeric values contained in them must be converted to numbers. Using the Val() function, only the part of the string before the first non-numeric character will be converted.

Therefore, if your text string contains a formatted number, the non-numeric characters added for formatting purposes must be removed. You can use the Replace function for that.

```
Dim Total As Double
Total = Val(Replace(TextBox1.Value, ",", "")) + Val(Replace(TextBox2.Value, ",", ""))
```